# Why the image of OSX Snow Leopard Installation DVD is 6.7G?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, installation

Isn't it the case that a DVD can only hold at most 4.7G of data? How can Apple fit these data into a DVD?

I discovered it when I tried to restore the install disk image to a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD#Dual-layer_recording)...

> Dual-layer recording (sometimes also known as double-layer recording) allows DVD-R and DVD+R discs to store significantly more data—up to 8.54 gigabytes per disc, compared with 4.7 gigabytes for single-layer discs.

Comment: +1 - Dual-Layer vs. Single-Layer is it.

Answer (score 1):

These are special types of DVD's.
You see it sometimes when you try to rip a film from a DVD. There are DVD's wich hold more than 4,7GB of data. Because 4,7GB is not enough, or otherwise to prevent the DVD from being copied. I've also got an old PC-game of Rayman here, wich is just a CD (it works in a CD-ROM-drive wich can't read DVD's, so no, I'm not mistaken), except that it holds 2,2GB of data.